# Java Convert a table of two Strings to a MAP<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java

I would like to convert a table of two Strings

to a MAP<'String, ArrayList<'String>>

Example : 
I get a table like this

```
hello world 
hi mom 
hi doug 
hello dad
```

I want to transform this in a map like this

```
hello, {world,dad,mom}
hi, {mom,doug}
```

Thanks a lot for the help :) 
I am disapointed ^^

Comment: A `Map<String,String`> CANT contain `{hello, world}, {hello, dad}, {hello, mom}` .. keys override each other. And show us what you have tried?

Comment: It's `Map` not `MAP`.

Comment: A Map is collection of  <key:value> pairs. Your use case is not clear.

Comment: what have you tried so far? `if(map.containsKey(myKey)){ map.get(myKey).add(newValue)};`

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @sanbhat Who said anything about `Map<String,String>`? I just read "table", not entirely sure what this refers to.

Comment: what you are looking for is a `Multimap` Google collections has what you need, I have already provided more effort than you have shown you have in your question. Show what *you* have tried!

Comment: @Dukeling the OP edited the heading.. without which I wouldn't have posted that comment!. OP had `Map<String,String>` instead of table in the question heading :-)

Comment: what about `hello my world`, what is your expected behaviour in this case? I hope it's not something like `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>>` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

// Loop through the table and assign the
// key/value to be checked and added to your map
... 

if(map.containsKey(key))
{
    map.get(key).add(value);
}
else
{
    ArrayList<String> newValueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    newValueList.add(value);

    map.put(key, newValueList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what i need and thanks others too :)

Answer (score 2):

- Initialize a `Map<String, List<String>>`, call it `map`
- Loop over your table's `k`, `v` entries and...

  - If `k` is not a key in the map already, add an entry mapping `k` to a new list containing `v`
  - If `k` is a key, add `v` to the list `map.get(k)`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this;

```
class Test{

   public static List<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static HashMap<String, List<String>> ohm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

         public static void main(String[] args){
       String insertStr = "Hello";
       ohm.put(insertStr, al1);

       if(ohm.containsKey(insertStr )) // DO SOME OPERATIONS HERE
       {
           ohm.get(insertStr).add("MOM");
           ohm.get(insertStr).add("World");
           ohm.get(insertStr).add("DAD");
           System.out.println(ohm.get(insertStr));

        }

    }
}
```

> **Output:**  [MOM, World, DAD]

Let me know if it helped, or you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapExample
{
    private static final String[] data = new String[] { "hello world", "hello dad", "hello mom", "hi mom", "hi doug" };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adjust the following as appropriate for actual data input and format 
        for(String s : data)
        {
            String[] splitData = s.split(" ");
            String key = splitData[0];
            String newValue = splitData[1];
            List<String> values = dataMap.get(key);
            if(values == null)
            {
                values = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            values.add(newValue);
            dataMap.put(key, values);
        }

        for(String key : dataMap.keySet())
        {
            System.out.print(key + ", { ");
            for(String value : dataMap.get(key))
            {
                System.out.print(value + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hello, { world dad mom }
hi, { mom doug }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TableToMap {

    private static String[] table = new String[] {"hello world", "hello mom", "hello dad"};
    private static Map <String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String row : table) {

            String[] splitString = row.split(" ");

            if (map.containsKey(splitString[0])) {
                map.get(splitString[0]).add(splitString[1]);
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();    
                newList.add(splitString[1]);

                map.put(splitString[0], newList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have built in multimap functionality, which is what you want here. You could make a custom map that, when you add a key value set such as `{"hello", "world"}` it checks to see if there is already a "hello" key first. If there is no "hello" key, then it adds a new `{hello, List<String>}` and then adds "world" to the mapped list. Otherwise, it just adds "world" to the list mapped to with "hello".

You can read more information about how to use maps and even how to obtain mutlimap functionality from:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html